# Carbon get month by number returns march for number 2

Tags: php, php-carbon

Has anyone ever had this bug before, or know a way to fix it?

I want to get a list of all months in the current year (start date and end date) in an array, so i'm doing like this (open to suggestions for cleaner easier ways)

```
//Create a months array
$months = [];
//Get start and end of all months
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
   $array = [];
   $array['start'] = Carbon::create()->month($i)->startOfMonth()->format('d/m/y');
   $array['end'] = Carbon::create()->month($i)->endOfMonth()->format('d/m/y');
   array_push($months, $array);
}
```

Which produces this result

[image]

As you can see, its looped and retrieved the months, but notice that it skips February completely and adds March twice.

If I manually run and return this code

```
return Carbon::create()->month(2)->startOfMonth()->format('d/m/y');
```

It returns `01/03/2018`.

Why does carbon print out March for month 2? Has anyone ever had this issue before or know of a way to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Carbon::create()->month(2)` will first create today's date, and then set the month to **2**, but *keep the other values*. Because today's date is the 29th of August, the date ends up referring to the 29th of February, which (this year at least) doesn't exist. PHP rolls these "fake" dates over into the next month, so **February 29th** becomes **March 1st**.

If you explicitly set the day of the month first, this should work as expected:

```
Carbon::create()->day(1)->month($i);
```

(Also, if you'd tried this yesterday it would have worked fine, and you might never have noticed the bug. If you tried it tomorrow, you would have ended up with March 2nd and probably noticed it a lot faster. Dates are great fun.)

Comment: Absolutely, I've just posted a very similiar answer at the same time after figuring it out myself. Will mark yours as the correct answer anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Figured this out whilst commenting on a suggested answer.

Its because todays date is 29th August 2018, and there are not 29 days in February.

Basically Carbon is creating an instance from todays date with `Carbon::create()` but then when using `->month(2)` will try to get the 29th Feb and error. It needs to work from the first of the month so change it to

```
 Carbon::create()->startOfMonth()->month($i)->startOfMonth()->format('d/m/y');
```

So it references from the 1st of the month and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Pure PHP is enough for this:

```
$datePeriod = new \DatePeriod(
    new \DateTimeImmutable(date('01-01-Y')),
    new \DateInterval('P1M'),
    new \DateTimeImmutable(date('31-12-Y'))
);

$dates = [];
foreach ($datePeriod as $date) {
     $dates[] = [
         'start' => $date->modify('first day of this month')->format('d/m/y'),
         'end' => $date->modify('last day of this month')->format('d/m/y'),
     ];   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the problem has now been solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's 0 based by the looks. so month(0) would be January, 1 = February, etc.
Change your loop to

```
for($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++){
   $array = [];
   $array['start'] = Carbon::create()->month($i)->startOfMonth()->format('d/m/y');
   $array['end'] = Carbon::create()->month($i)->endOfMonth()->format('d/m/y');
   array_push($months, $array);
}
```

Comment: I initially tried this, but it returns `01/12/17` as the first date then continues to do the same after, so it prints `01/01/18`,`01/03/18`,`01/03/18`,`01/04/18`. It obviously something to do with the amount of days that are in Feb that it doesn't like.

Comment: I figured it out whilst replying to your answer, will post an answer now.