# How pass month value and get start and end date of month In laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am a new Laravel and using Laravel 5.5.

I want to pass value of month and get start and end date of passing month.

Suppose pass 5 (May month) the get value 
Start date: 01-05-2019 
End date: 30-05-2019

I have tried:

```php
$finalMonth = 5;
$startMonth = Carbon::now()->addMonth($finalMonth)->day(1)->format("Y-m-d");
$endMonth = Carbon::now()->addMonth($finalMonth)->endOfMonth()->format("Y-m-d");
```

But It's given the wrong result because of it adds current month+pass month.
Means 4+5=9 that means sept.

Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using:

```php
$startMonth = Carbon::now()->addMonth($finalMonth)->day(1)->format("Y-m-d");
```

Use instead the `month` method:

```
$startMonth = Carbon::now()->month($finalMonth)->day(1)->format("Y-m-d");
```

**See:** [carbon-get-month-by-number-returns-march-for-number-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52072758/carbon-get-month-by-number-returns-march-for-number-2)

Answer (score 0):

Use instead Below :

```
$startMonth = Carbon::now()->month($finalMonth)->day(1)->format("Y-m-d");
```